# Using LDAP to find Users in Active Directory - no Users?

Tags: python-2.7, active-directory, ldap

Using (python-ldap 2.4.17.0) I am trying to get a list of all our users (username) from AD (Active Directory).
When I execute the code below it only gives a list of Domain info, DNS servers, stuff about Exchange Servers - I can't seem to find anything to do with users from AD - even though when I go to the server and look at Active directory under the base/root node - there is a CN=Users, and all the good stuff I need underneath there!!!
But this does not reflect in the code.  Anyone know why I can't see the Users via the code?

```
import ldap

def main():

    con=ldap.initialize('ldap://192.168.16.12:389')
    try:
        res =con.search_s("DC=mycompany,DC=local", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE)
        for dn, entry in res:
        print dn
except Exception, error:
    print error
```

---

RESULT

```
DC=mycompany,DC=local
DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mycompany,DC=local
DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=EXCH-FOOPLACE,CN=Public Folder Database 2,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Mycompany,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=EXCHANGE01,CN=Barplace-RegularMailBoxes,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Mycompany,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=EXCHANGE01,CN=Barplace-LargeMailBoxes,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Mycompany,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=EXCHANGE01,CN=Public Database,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Mycompany,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=EXCH-FOOPLACE,CN=Houston-Exchange02,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Mycompany,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mycompany,DC=local
```

Comment: Where are your users Located. (Typically they would be: "OU=Users,"DC=mycompany,DC=local")  Change "DC=mycompany,DC=local" to "OU=Users,"DC=mycompany,DC=local"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out that you actually have to provide some kind of authorized user credentials before you query LDAP to get a fully comprehensive list of entities e.g.:

```
con=ldap.initialize('ldap://192.168.16.12:38')

user_dn = r"Administrator@foo.com"
password = "bar"

criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))"
attributes = ['displayName', 'company']

try:
    con.simple_bind_s(user_dn, password)
    res =con.search_s("CN=Users,DC=foo,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(objectClass=User)')
    for dn, entry in res:
        print dn
except Exception, error:
    print error
```

Comment: Did you intend to use criteria and attributes in the search_s method call?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is similar to @Vidar, but slightly expanded:

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.example.com")
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

    bind = l.simple_bind_s("me@example.com", "password")

    base = "dc=example, dc=com"
    criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))"
    attributes = ['displayName', 'company']
    result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)

    results = [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]
    print results

finally:
    l.unbind()
```

(c) https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Active_Directory/Search_for_a_user#Python

Comment: _slightly expanded_ and yet without any comments about what this code does better :\